# Weird Wireless Issue - Looks like lost connection, but not really

Tags: network, wifi

Well, this is really hard to explain.

I have two macs at home, a late 2012 macbook pro and a early 2012 macbook air. I also have some other gadgets with android and firefox OS. My wife had, before the macbook air, a hp notebook with windows 7, and I had a dell with arch linux.

When I had that old dell with arch linux, sometimes, the internet just stop to work. I never minded because my wife laptop with windows 7 didn't had that bug, so, I taught it was a hardware issue, since it was a pretty old machine.

Anyways, now, both of us have macs, and that same problem happens with both of us. Sometimes with Androids too, but, in macs, it happens very often. Sometimes I just have to turn wireless on and off again several times in a minute...

I investigate the system.log and found nothing interesting. At network.log, i found this:

```
Wed Sep 25 00:05:32.095 <airportd[80]> _handleLinkEvent: Unable to process link event, op mode request returned -3903 (Operation not supported)
```

But it doesn't happens every time I have connection problems. I pretty new to OSX and can't found any other log files with useful information...

What happen is that the internet stops working, but the network icon still "darker", i.e., it still connected, but I can't access even my home network.

Do anyone have any idea about that? The router is a ISP-provided tecnicolor td5130, seems like it only exists in brazil.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on our description it is the router problem. To clarify, you are still connected to the router but the router is not connected to ISP. To verify during the down time, pull up the router remote set up (the IP for that is on the back of the router or in the manuals, usually something like 192.168.1.254 or 192.168.1.1. If you get the router set up screen you are connected, but you can also view the router status.

Comment: Alternatively, there is a light on your router that should show if it is connected to internet.

Comment: Open System Preferences + Network, click on Assist me, choose Diagnostics, follow the instructions. That will test your connection. Tell us what happened.

Comment: Sorry, I think you understand me wrong. The router still connected to the internet.. The wifi icon still "darker", indicating that it still connected to the router, but I can't access the internet or router or anything else. Then I shut wifi off and on again and it works for while.. than the same thing happens..

Comment: Well, then hold the "alt" key and press on the wifi icon, then you will see details of your wifi connection. The darker icon does not provide any relevant information. Also, I highly recommend running the wifi test as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bought another router and aparently the issue disapear.